# How to pass values from one Html to another Html page?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 html pages are there (Html1, Html2). In Html1 i am displaying first name,last name. And i am providing link for that. When i click hyperlink Link i want to pass that data to "Html2" page.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
                                <div class="product">
                                    <img src="#:ImageUrl#" alt=""  />
                                    <h3>Price: #:Price#</h3><br/>
                                    <h3>Mls\#: #:ListingID#</h3><br/>
                                    <h3>Beds: #:Bedrooms#</h3><br/>
                                    <h3>Baths: #:Bathrooms#</h3><br/>
                                    <h3><a href='SampleHTML.html' target="_blank" style="font-weight:bold;">#:Address#</a></h3>
                                </div>
                            </script>
```

Can any one can help me on this?

Thanks
Krishna.

Comment: You are using html helper for hyperlink??

Comment: just show your hyperlink...

Comment: No i am not using any helper.

Comment: just post hyperlink code..

Comment: Share your code, please. If you are using an `ActionLink` to move to another page, you can pass parameters in the link. If you want to do it this way, share your controller code and your HTML code for both pages. Otherwise, you could use the ViewBag, ViewData, or Session variables.

Comment: I am not using this one in MVC. I want to do this one in Html itself.

Comment: below answer is simple html only where #:firstname# i where your firstname is stored..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use querystring as shown :-

```
<a href='SampleHTML.html?firstname=' + #:firstname# + '&lastname=' + #:lastname# target="_blank" style="font-weight:bold;">#:Address#</a>
```

Comment: I tried same way, but values are not displaying in second html page.

Comment: For example i am displaying default details (Bedrooms : 3, Id : 4) like that. when i click hyperlink those details should display in another html page with respected area details should display.

Comment: When i use your suggestion values are displaying in URL. I want to display those values in another page.

Comment: @murali53..then retrieve those querystring values on another page with javascript or jquery..

Comment: @murali53..i think my answer worked for as your querystring have firstname and lastname as per your question..if you have another problem than please post it in on stackoverflow..if answer solved your problem then plz accept it so that it may help other users also..thankzz....

Comment: For using query string it's fine based on your suggestion. But i am displaying some data in "html1" page (Price,Id), when i click the hyperlink  those details should display in "Html2" page.

Comment: @murali53...querystring is the only solution for your problem if you need more data you can append that also with querystring as shown in my answer....